# youtube player in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, youtube

I have the url video on youtube and I want to play the video in the youtube default application on the blackberry without invoking the browser to play

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You forgot to `enter code here`

Comment: I think he's asking us to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I've never found a way to do this.  The [BlackBerry Invoke class does not have a constant defined for the Youtube app](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/Invoke.html#APP_TYPE_ADDRESSBOOK), which is what you can use to open other built-in apps.

I know this isn't what you'd **prefer** to do, but a couple other alternatives are:

- open Youtube videos in the Browser, like this:

```java
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciB6ExQa5SM");
```

- take a look at the [BlackBerry Youtube Client sample](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/YouTube%20Client), which would allow you to build an embedded Youtube player.  A companion [blog post can also be found here](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/01/communication-api-2/).  **Note**: the sample probably won't display video in a simulator, as I think you need to have a valid cellular carrier setup (APN settings, etc.) for the network to allow youtube streaming.